# mouseover mouse out nt working in IE8

Tags: jquery, css

[image: Ad Blocks Page Image]

Dear All,

I have this page in which if i mouseover on any orange ad block, then blue dashed border comes and on click of each ad block the respective info is displayed.

I have the code block in JQuery as

```
var cssObj = {
  'border' : 'Dashed 2px #3B5998'
}

var cssObj2 = {
  'border' : 'none'
}


     $(".gil_Ads_AdOverState1").mouseover(function(){

        $(this).css(cssObj);

     }).mouseout(function(){

        $(this).css(cssObj2);

     });          

     $(".gil_Ads_AdOverState1").click(function(){ 

           $('#gDescZone1').hide();
           $('#gDescZone2').hide();
           $('#descAd2').hide();
           $('#descAd3').hide();
           $('#descAd4').hide();
           $('#descAd1').fadeIn();
     });
```

It is working fine in Chrome while same is not working in IE8... May i know what is the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't doing the mouseover borders with css?

Comment: ? he is doing it with css hence the cssObj at the top of the page.

Comment: See my answer for what I meant.  I see how I my comment was confusing.

Comment: Basic test works just fine in IE8 with your exact code: http://jsfiddle.net/7N87m/ so, it must be something else. Post more code and we'll see..

Answer (score 0):

Take the mouseovers out of your javascript and use CSS like normal ;)

```
.gil_Ads_AdOverState1{
  border: none;
}
.gil_Ads_AdOverState1:hover{
  border: 2px dashed #3B5998;
}
```

That's the more accepted way to do it

Also I think it has to be `width style color` in that order for border, not sure if it'll work in all browsers if you do the wrong order of parameters.

If you haven't already make sure your JS is wrapped in $(document).ready() like so:

```
$(function(){
  $(".gil_Ads_AdOverState1").click(function(){ 

         $('#gDescZone1').hide();
         $('#gDescZone2').hide();
         $('#descAd2').hide();
         $('#descAd3').hide();
         $('#descAd4').hide();
         $('#descAd1').fadeIn();
   });
});
```

Could you update your question with your current JS and current CSS?

Comment: I have done the Hover state Border in Css now But still not working.. and in Chrome it is working fine..

Comment: Do you have a DTD defined at the top of your page's html?  It might look something like `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`  (Pulled from the source of this web page), depending on which version of html you wish to be adhering to.  I have definitely gotten hover border states to work using CSS in IE8.  From w3schools:  `In Internet Explorer, there must be declared a  <!DOCTYPE> for the :hover selector to work on other elements than the <a> element.`

Comment: I have this DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: @Shabir have you tried wrapping your javascript in the $(document).ready(function(){}) block?  or it's shortcut $(function(){})?  See my edited answer for clarification

Comment: @nzifnb @andyb thank you very much for your response. I fixed the problem, basically my div not having bg color as Orange as mentioned in Image and when i applied the same orange color to the div it worked in IE...

Answer (score 0):

Following works OK for me in Chrome and IE8. However when I tested it in IE8 the "Active X" popup appeared asking if I wanted to run the JavaScript. The jQuery hover will not work without allowing IE to run scripted content. It might be the case that your IE8 has the preference set to always disable scripting (or is prompting you and you just missed it). Note that the CSS `:hover` will only work on `<a>` tags in IE6.

Hope this helps :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .bar:hover {
        border:2px dashed blue;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $('.foo').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('border','2px dashed red');
 }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('border','none');
 });   
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="foo">List item hover with jQuery css()</li>
    <li class="bar">List item hover with CSS</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="bar">Anchor</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had now created the hover state of my div in Css (Blue Dashed Borders as in image) and now i have just wrote the function in which i hide some divs and fadeIn another dive.. It still nt works in IE but it works in Chrome My JQ code is as below '$('.gil_Ads_AdOverState1').click(function(){ 
        
           $('#gDescZone1').hide();
           $('#gDescZone2').hide();
           $('#descAd2').hide();
           $('#descAd3').hide();
           $('#descAd4').hide();
           $('#descAd1').fadeIn();
     }); ' I dont know what happens to this...

Comment: Did you try the **exact** code in my answer on IE8? If that does not work in IE8 then it is either your browser's security settings stopping the script running, or the script contains errors or you are not including jQuery correctly.

Comment: Great, so IE8 is running JavaScript. It sounds like there is a JavaScript error somewhere but I am not sure why it only affect IE8. Is it possible for you to post the full page you are having problems with? Or creating a test case on http://jsfiddle.net/